# Is having an entity named Order an issue with nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Is having an entity named Order an issue with nhibernate?

**Update**

I ask because, it does!

I just ran sql profile, and when I run the code that they generate I get an error saying:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.

(or I have some issue with my mapping??)

Comment: The reason I asked my question is that you should always put as much information into the question as possible. If not, you're going to get answers that doesn't really answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All you need is to use the class from the right namespace.

As for mapping, try using "[Order]" as a table name instead of "Order".

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I have a model object called Order, no problems.